# Passing abstract/generic object to method

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AdvancedModel<T, K>
```

that has two subclasss:

```
public class TrackModel extends AdvancedModel<Track, Toptracks>
```

and

```
public class ArtistModel extends AdvancedModel<Artist, Topartists>
```

In a seperate Class called Evaluation, I want to have a method that takes in either of these objects and do stuff with it. Is there a way to do this using the generic type, or will I have to have the same method twice using the two different classes as parameters?

EDIT

I tried

```
private <T, K> float runModel(AdvancedModel<T, K> testEngine)
```

which seems to work when i declare the objects earlier like:

```
AdvancedModel<Track, Toptracks> name = new TrackModel(10, 17);

float result = runModel(name);
```

This is however causing issues with other methods later on. For example, I have an other method which i want to either call getArtist() or getTrack() from K, depending on whether K is Toptracks or Topartists?

Comment: " I want to have a method that takes in either of these objects and do stuff with it" - yes you can, but unless you specify what kind of "stuff" you want to do - we can't really help you...

Comment: you can use base class

Comment: It depends what your method is doing. If it's able to operate on the base class without knowing about `T` or `K`, it can accept `AdvancedModel<?, ?>`.

Comment: Please show what other issues you are experiencing with other methods

Comment: Is difficult to assess without knowing more details but the fact that a task may need to call a different method depending on the type of the argument suggest perhaps these two classes should have a common interface or superclass and offer the same operation ```get``` or ```getElement``` or something like that and then that mehod would only need to call ```get``` whatever the input.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with `T` and/or `K` in your method, you may want to give the classes used for `T` and or `K` a common abstract superclass or a common interface. If you declare, say, `public abstract class AdvancedModel<T extends AbstractThing, K extends AbstractTopThings>`, your method may call methods in the `AbstractThing` and/or the `AbstractTopThings` interface or class.

Comment: If we’re to understand, not to mention help you with the “issues with other methods later on”, you’d better be specific about what errors or misbehaving you are observing.

Answer (score 3):

You should add type parameters to your method declaration as following:

```
public <T, K> void doStuffWithAdvancedModel(AdvancedModel<T, K> model) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I tried

private <T, K> float runModel(AdvancedModel<T, K> testEngine)
which seems to work when i declare the objects earlier like:

AdvancedModel<Track, Toptracks> name = new TrackModel(10, 17);

float result = runModel(name);
This is however causing issues with other methods later on. For example, I have an other method which i want to either call getArtist() or getTrack() from K, depending on whether K is Toptracks or Topartists?

Comment: Generics (as it follows from name) are used for _generalization_. If you need to deal with some specific types like `Toptracks` or `Topartists` and call their specific methods you should create separate methods having exactly `Toptack` or `Topartist` as parameters.